# Mongo engine query the referencefield

Tags: python, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I have define the class statement:

```py
from mongoengine import *
class TickDataDocument(Document):
"""
"""
    instrument_id = StringField(max_length=10, unique=True, required=True)
    tick_data = ReferenceField(TickDocument)


class TickDocument(Document):
"""
"""
    price = DecimalField(precision=2, required=True) 
    volume = LongField(required=True)  
    turnover = DecimalField(precision=2, required=True)  
    update_time = DateTimeField(unique=True, required=True)
```

I want to query the update_time in some period of time.

```
 TickDataDocument.objects(instrument_id="fa1100").filter(tick_data__ update_time__lt =datetime.datetime(2013,9,3))
```

but I got **errors:**

> mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot perform join in mongoDB:
>   tick_data__update_time

How could I to five a solution to query the inner reference field in mongoengine.

Comment: can you make it two different queries ? first to get the tickdatadocuments and querying for these documents in tickDocument ?

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in a comment, I do this in two steps (two queries):

```
tick_docs = list(TickDocument.object(update_time__lt)=datetime.datetime(2013,9,3))

TickDataDocument.objects(instrument_id="fa1100").filter(tick_data__in=tick_docs)
```

If there is any simpler solution, I'm interested as well.

Comment: Is it a only way? If `TickDocument` has too many rows, maybe it occur memory issue.

Comment: @Hide yes there is, check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [aggregate](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate) method in mongoengine and use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) syntax to make your join and query, be aware the using the aggregate method returns a cursor object, not a QuerySet.

### Example

```py
TickDataDocument.objects().aggregate([
    {"$match":{"instrument_id":"fa1100"}},
    {"$lookup":{
        "from": TickDocument._get_collection_name(),
        "localField": "tick_data",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "tick"            
    }},
    {"$match":{
        "tick.update_time":{"$lt":datetime.datetime(2013,9,3)}
    }}
])
```